# List transactions after losing wallet and private key?

Tags: transactions, bitcoind, wallet, private-key

I have made various transactions with my wallet using bitcoind. If I lose my wallet (and private key) and somebody else somehow knows my private key and does some transactions, is it possible for me to somehow get a list of those new transactions?

Answer (score 1):

If you have your wallet.dat in the Bitcoin core and someone else for some reason knows a private key that is associated with this wallet.dat, this person can spend the Bitcoins of that private key in basically, any other wallet, if this person does that, you will see this transaction in your Bitcoin core as the type "Sent to".

If you like to test it you can type `listunspent` in your Bitcoin core, then you will see the addresses with an amount to be spendable, then you can copy any of these addresses and take the private key for that address using the command `dumpprivkey address`, take this private key and import in any other wallet then send the Bitcoin to some other wallet.

Comment: Let's assume I have lost wallet.dat and forgot the private key, but somebody else has spent bitcoins using my private key. Can I somehow know the newer transactions if I only have the old transactions list?

Comment: Yes, you need to know the address, and you probably can get this address from the old transaction list, but you will probably need to look one by one in a block explorer.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a list of old transaction IDs for transactions in which you received money, you can use those in one of the  blockchain explorers to find the Bitcoin addresses of the transaction outputs. You can then see if those outputs have been subsequently spent. You will be able to see the transaction-IDs of the transactions that spend the outputs.